# Changing div css properties through input:checked

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the width and height of a div on the click of a checkbox (#navigation). I know I can change other elements like span through

```
#navigation input:checked ~ span { }
```

but when I try

```
#navigation input:checked { }
```

I don't get the same result. Is there a way of doing this through css or am I out of luck?

My html would be as follows...

```
<nav id="navigation">
 <input type="checkbox" />
 <ul><li>heading1</li><li>heading2</li><li>heading3</li></ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D What do you mean? I've provided a simplified code snippet, haven't I?

Comment: There's no HTML.....CSS doesn't tell the whole story. I'm suspecting you have a "Parent Selector" issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D Alright, updated. Yes it is a parent does this mean it isn't possible?

Comment: That's right...you can't affect the parent by doing something with the child. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?rq=1 You'd need Javascript

Comment: Thanks Paulie at least I know what's wrong now.